# Form not sending because url I'm building somehow isn't accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

Thanks for looking. I'm pretty new to JS and I'm hoping this is just a simple answer staring me in the face that I'm missing.

I'm working on a chunk of JS for sending a form to Sales Force. Sales Force needs a 'success' URL to redirect to. Instead of hardcoding it I want to detect the domain where the site visitor is and serve a thank-you page from that domain. Right now the site is in testing and some less technical people will be handling the full launch (don't ask) and they don't want to have to go digging through JS files at launch time but still want to be able to test now.

You can see a commented out line, that one works but the URL I build doesn't.

```
var domainCustomerIsUsing = document.domain;
var thankYouURL = 'http://'+domainCustomerIsUsing+'/thank-you-newsletter';
var salesForceForm = $('<form>').attr('method', 'POST').attr('action', 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8').css('display', 'none');
// salesForceForm.append(createInput('retURL', 'http://google.com'));
salesForceForm.append(createInput('retURL', thankYouURL));
```

It is a jQuery form but the bit where I am trying to build the URL is not jQuery. I've removed bits of the form for client confidentiality but I think this shows everything I need to.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You state that the url you build doesn't work; is it giving a JavaScript error, redirecting the user to the wrong place or whats the problem? On a different related matter, are any of the code above in some functions or something?

Comment: Quite so, @Niklas - the answers to those questions are required to be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you alert the result for the URL you build and the output from `createInput`? This works for me just pasting it into the Chrome console on this page:

```
var domainCustomerIsUsing = document.domain;
var thankYouURL = 'http://'+domainCustomerIsUsing+'/thank-you-newsletter';
var url = 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';
var salesForceForm = $('<form>').attr('method', 'POST')
                                .attr('action', url)
                                .css('display', 'none');
salesForceForm.append($("<input>").attr("name", "retURL")
                                  .val(thankYouURL));
salesForceForm.submit();
```

My money is on `$("<input")` being built incorrectly.

Comment: The top part of your response alerted me to the fact that it had to be the createInput function. Went to check it and found that I somehow must have deleted the first line of the function where I created it. It wasn't working because the function just didn't exist. The main problem all along was between the keyboard and the chair. 

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.